# chart.js / angular-chart line outside style issue

Tags: javascript, charts, angular-chart

I have a strange issue with angular-chart.js (which use chart.js).
If I set and block the min and max values for yAxis,  when the line goes out of the limits the style is strange. Do you have an idea about what occurs ?

[image]

[image]

Here is the configuration for each 3 chart :

```
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
    responsive: true,
    animation: false,
    pointDot: false,
    colours: [{ // blue
        fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(51,87,205,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(51,87,205,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(51,87,205,1)',
        pointHighlightFill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        bezierCurve: true,
        pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
        datasetStroke: false,
    }, { // blue
        fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        strokeColor: '#FB3333',
        pointColor: '#FB3333',
        pointStrokeColor: '#FB3333',
        pointHighlightFill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    }],
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    showXLabels: 10,
    showTooltips: true,
    multiTooltipTemplate: function(label) {

        return label.datasetLabel + " : " + label.value.toFixed(1);
    }


});
```

And for each chart I applied an other configuration :

```
    $scope.optionsG1 = {
    scaleStartValue: -2,
    scaleStepWidth: 1,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 4
};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you provide the cod, how you configure angular-chart, not only the images?

Comment: Ok I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Set `bezierCurve: false` for the charts where you are having this problem.